# PhpStorm не видит симлинки

Tags: phpstorm

PhpStorm не видит симлинки в проекте.

Структура папки portal проекта:

```
.
..
404.php
.access.php
.admin.menu.php
ajax
au787.php
bitrix -> /var/www/vhosts/lk.--------.ru/htdocs/bitrix
catalogue
cmanager
cron_events
desktop_app
docs
download
help
.htaccess
include -> /var/www/vhosts/lk.--------.ru/htdocs/include
index
index.php
local -> /var/www/vhosts/lk.--------.ru/htdocs/local
news
offers
personal
pricelist
register
robots.txt
.section.php
services
settings
sitemap
sql.php
test
.top.menu.php
upload -> /var/www/vhosts/lk.--------.ru/htdocs/upload
urlrewrite.php
```

После импорта проекта в PhpStorm симлинки пропали: http://prntscr.com/lgayvx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhpStorm в общем-то не причём. Проблему удалось решить пересозданием симлинков в папке с проектом в Windows. Для этого была использована команда cmd-консоли: mklink. Синтаксис команды: mklink /j path_for_link path_to_original_file_or_folder